# Remove an ng-model created variable when the associated html input is removed from the DOM

Tags: angularjs

There is a html input with an ng-model attribute for two way binding to a view model. The input may be removed (using ng-if) depending on other inputs, and when this removal occurs I would like the view model variable to also be removed.

Using ng-show/hide instead of ng-if may also be an option.

Here's a mini-app demonstrating the scenario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app ng-init="mdl.foo = 'wibble'">

    <label for="radioA">A:</label>
    <input id="radioA" type="radio" ng-model="mdl.selec" value="A" /><br />
    <label for="radioB">B:</label>
    <input id="radioB" type="radio" ng-model="mdl.selec" value="B" /><br />
    <div ng-if="mdl.selec==='A'">
        <strong>Hello World</strong>
        <label for="textInput">Text:</label>
        <input id="textInput" type="text" ng-model="mdl.foo" />
    </div>
    <strong>{{mdl.foo}}</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Have attached demo code to the Q.

Comment: @charlietfl perhaps the behaviour is dependent on angular version or some global option?

Comment: Use a watch on whatever variable needs to trigger the removal, or use an event listener that would trigger it. Then just do `delete $scope.mdl.propertyName`